# Limit XPath matches (or choose match index) at location step

Tags: xpath

I want to limit the number of matches, or better yet, choose which indexed match, is made at a location step in XPath.

I know that if I have the following document:

```xml
<blah>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      <target>one</target>
      <target>two</target>
    </bar>
    <bar>
      <target>three</target>
      <target>four</target>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</blah>
```

I can limit the expression to only include the first `<bar>` directly under `<foo>` like the following, in order to only return `<target>one</target>` and `<target>two</target>`:

`//foo/bar[1]/target`

But now what if I have this:

```xml
<blah>
  <foo>
    <blah>
      <bar>
        <target>one</target>
        <target>two</target>
      </bar>
    </blah>
    <blah>
      <bar>
        <target>three</target>
        <target>four</target>
      </bar>
    </blah>
  </foo>
</blah>
```

I still only want the expression to yield `<target>one</target>` and `<target>two</target>`. But the following doesn't work; it will actually match `<bar>` under each `<foo><blah>`

`//foo//bar[1]/target`

Apparently there is a subtle distinction: `bar[1]` means "the first child of some element", not "the first element that matches this location step in the path expression".

How can I limit the expression (without naming the `<blah>` elements, because they can vary) so that when it reaches the `//foo//bar` location it only retains the first match of `<bar>` before it continues matching the expression?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, with just a few more seconds of thought I found the answer! (Actually forming the question helped me discover the solution.)

The secret is simply to use parentheses:

`(//foo//bar)[1]/target`

If I'm understanding it correctly, the expression `//foo//bar[1]` says, "for every `… <bar>` you match, only take the first one of them for the parent", so if there are multiple "first-bars", it will take each of the "first-bars".

Instead the expression `(//foo//bar)[1]` says "once you match `… <bar>`, only take the first matching one; *then* evaluate the rest of the path from that one matching `<bar>`.

Whew! I wish every road bump could be this simple to get past.